# Pointers and references in linked lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

int main()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;

    node* nu = new node;
    std::cout << *&nu << std::endl;
}
```

The question: is `nu` a memory address, are pointers really just memory address or is there something that I am missing here. What significance does *nu have, is this the object contained in the address, `&nu` gives me the memory address itself. if `nu` had been an integer it would have given me a number?. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: This should be covered in any introductory text. Perhaps try one of these [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `*&nu` is the same as just `nu`.  You are taking the address of `nu` itself (not the address of the `node` that it holds), and are then dereferencing that to get back to `nu` itself. So `std::cout << *&nu` and `std::cout << nu` output the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is nu a memory address, are pointers really just memory address or is there something that I am missing here.

`nu` is a pointer to a `node` and it means that `nu` "points to" a memory location (in this case on the heap) where the `node` has been constructed. The memory location is the address and so yes `nu` is essentially a memory address. If you print it, you would get a hex value - the address itself.

> What significance does *nu have, is this the object contained in the address

Syntax such as `*nu` (or generally `*pointer`) translates to reaching to where the pointer points. The `*`, which is called **dereference operator**, is used in C++ to get the value behind the pointer.

> &nu gives me the the memory address itself.

The `&` is the way to acquire the address of a variable. Writing `&nu` means that you want to get the address of the `nu` variable. Note that it is not the address of the `node` but the **`nu`** variable itself. This variable lives in the memory too (on the stack) and so has the address.

> if nu had been an integer it would have given me a number?

No, you would get the address as well. `&` gives you the address of the variable, not the value. It might feel tricky with a pointer because the value of the pointer is the address.

> *&nu

In this case you've acquired the address of `nu` variable (&n) and immediately reached for the value behind it (*&nu). It is equivalent of just `nu` because the value is the address of the `node` somewhere on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

`&nu` uses the address-of operator to get the address of the pointer, resulting in a pointer to the pointer. The `*` indirection operator then gets the contents of the new pointer, which is the value of the original pointer `nu` and is what you're sending to `cout`.